# Mapping fields between JSON schemas

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I currently get JSON payload from a rest end point, in which I have to do mapping/transformation on to store afterwards to a mongo DB (still as JSON Object).

To give an example, let's assume that below is the source JSON

```
{
   "location": "London",
   "temp": 15,
   "weather": "Cloudy"
}
```

And this needs to be stored in a Mongo DB still in json, however the field `location` needs to be mapped to be `place` instead as such

```
{
   "place": "London",
   "temp": 15,
   "weather": "Cloudy"
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this through Jackson (on a large scale, I have almost 400 fields) other than creating custom deserialiser?

Comment: You may use `@JsonAlias("location") @JsonProperty("place")  private String place;` - this should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@JsonAlias` may be used for deserialized value:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder(alphabetic = true)
public class Source {
    @JsonAlias("temp")
    int temperature; 

    @JsonAlias("location")
    @JsonProperty("place")
    String place;

    String weather;
// getters/setters
}
// testing
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
String json = "{\"location\": \"London\",\n" +
                "   \"temp\": 15,\n" +
                "   \"weather\": \"Cloudy\"\n" +
                "}";
Source src = om.readValue(json, Source.class);
System.out.println(om.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(src));
```

Output (temperature field using actual property name in the POJO):

```
{
  "place" : "London",
  "temperature" : 15,
  "weather" : "Cloudy"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have built on the solution @Alex provided above and came up with a non invasive solution that overrides the JSON class without changing it using Jackson's [MixIns](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations).

I had to do this because I am using JSON schema to generate the POJOs, hence I cannot introduce any changes to them.

Let's assume we have a source class with a property named `originalProperty` that we want to map to be named `mixedProperty`

```
class Source {
    @JsonProperty("originalProperty")
    int originalProperty;

    @JsonProperty("anotherProperty")
    int anotherProperty;
}
```

For this, we create a `MixIn` class, which is typically a class that contains only the properties that we want to override

```
class MixIn {
    @JsonProperty("mixedProperty")
    @JsonAlias("originalProperty")
    int originalProperty;
}
```

Notice here that we have changed the `@JsonProperty` annotation to refer to the new property name `mixedProperty`, and added a new annotation `@JsonAlias` with the original property name `originalProperty`

All set, now when you need to mix it all together

```
class JsonCooker {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String originalJson = "{\"originalProperty\": 1, \"anotherProperty\" :2 }";

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Source updatedSource = objectMapper
                .addMixIn(Source.class, MixIn.class)
                .readValue(originalJson, Source.class);

        String updatedJson = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(updatedSource);
        System.out.println(updatedJson);
    }
}
```

And the result would be

```
{
  "mixedProperty" : 1,
  "anotherProperty" : 2
}
```